# OBD2 BLE Communication - how to send AT commands and receive data

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

I have a OBD2 dongle and need to get the speed of a vehicle through it (using BLE and iOS device). The documentation that came with the dongle didn't mention services and characteristics but with some debugging I discovered a few. Let's call them service 1, 2, 3.

1. Service 1 has one characteristic with Read property and WriteWithoutResponse property
2. Service 2 has one characteristic with Read property and Notify property
3. Service 3 has two characteristics: Characteristic A with Read property and Notify property and Characteristic B with Write property and WriteWithoutResponse property

How to know which characteristic/s I need to send AT commands and receive the corresponding data and then how to initiate this communication. I need to be able to get the speed in particular. Thank you in advance.

I have tried the following but nothing happened:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

        if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        }

        if characteristic.properties.contains(.write) {
            let commandString = "010D\r"
            if let commandData = commandString.data(using: .utf8) {
                peripheral.writeValue(commandData, for: characteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
                peripheral.writeValue(commandData, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And then expecting something in:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    if let value = characteristic.value {
        let text = String(data: value, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.onNotifyReceived(text)
    }

}
```

Comment: If the Characteristic are "0xAAAA"( four hex), in theory they should be documented by the Bluetooth Organization, check there doc. If not, "How to know which characteristic/s I need to send AT commands" That's just reverse engineering.

Comment: @Larme They are not documented here - https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services - if this is what you mean. I am almost sure which service and characteristics I should use - the service with the write and the notify characteristic. But not completely sure. More wondering why it does not work if it is really this one. Maybe my code is just wrong.

Comment: It doesn't write? Well, if it only accept array of integer for instance, your command is invalid. Why should `"010D\r"` turned into `Data` using UTF8 encoding be a valid message? Who told you that?

Comment: @Larme You are probably right. At first iteration I initiated the communication to OBD2 emulator (didn't have the dongle then) via WiFi. And I sent the data this way using a socket. It was working well. But I need it to work over BLE and maybe I should send the data another way and expect something else. Is there a way to figure this out without it being documented?

Comment: As said previously, that's "Reverse Engineering". If you can read it, and has values, I guess that the sending value should be of the same kind. But that's a long way ahead of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, if you're talking via e.g., an ELM327 – which is among the most common OBD2 chips – you better not start with PIDs (like `010D`), but rather initialize it with the proper `AT` command sequence (see the respective manual for details on this).

Next, `peripheralDidUpdateNotificationState` is the wrong delegate method. This is triggered whenever you subscribe or unsubscribe to a characteristic, not whenever its value changes. You want to implement the delegate method `peripheralDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic` instead.

That said, the trouble is: OBD2 BLE adapters don't use any fixed GATT profiles. The way most (if not all) BLE OBD2 adapters work, is that they offer one service with one or two characteristics:

- A write characteristic. This one is where the mobile device can write its AT commands (in the case of, e.g., an ELM327) and PIDs to.
- A notify characteristic. This is the one where the results from the car (ECUs) are returned.

Once you have access to these characteristics, you can implement the OBD2 serial protocol (e.g. using a command queue that writes and waits for the response, before transmitting the finished command to the application layer).

Some BLE adapters merge these two into one characteristic. If you want to support arbitrary adapters, you will have to add a 'select your adapter' screen where you probe the found adapters, remember the characteristics, and then communicate.

That way it's possible to write apps that work with all kinds of BLE OBD2 adapters (and not only support a selected handful of vendors), such as OBD2 Expert (Disclaimer: I'm the author of that software).

Comment: Is the communication just done by writing values to the peripheral and then reading the values in `peripheralDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic`? Or should there be something more?

Comment: You're correct, that's basically all it takes. By the way, I have published my OBD2 library @ https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive – perhaps it's of help.

Comment: It is a great library. I have tried using it for our needs, but for some reason the value I am getting is not the expected one (in `formattedResponse`). Debugging is really not easy, because I cannot find a good simulator. Do you by any chance know a good simulator for OBD2 (that is also not too expensive)?

Comment: If you're serious about OBD2 development (with regards to trying different standard vehicle protocols), I recommend the https://www.diamex.de/dxshop/Diamex-OBD2-Profi-Simulator-alle-Protokolle, which is around 300€, but worth every penny.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer could you please take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090365/what-ble-characteristic-should-i-use-in-a-ble-ios-device-for-obdii