# What BLE characteristic should I use in a BLE IOS device for OBDII

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

Hello  I am wondering what write and notify characteristic I should use from this OBDII BLE device/Dongle?: 
I want to create a program for IOS in Flutter.
There are quite a few

```
 : Device name: VEEPEAK Device id: 34E2B2AF-60F4-9362-DBF6-AD750321AABA
Number of discovered Services: 3
Service Service: UUID: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
  Charac.: UUID: 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
     Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
  Charac.: UUID: 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
 Charac.: UUID: 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
 Charac.: UUID: 00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
 Charac.: UUID: 00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
 Charac.: UUID: 00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
 Charac.: UUID: 00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false
 Charac.: UUID: 00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   Can read: true Can write: false  Can notify: false

Service Service: UUID: 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455
  Charac.: UUID: 49535343-6daa-4d02-abf6-19569aca69fe
    Can read: true Can write: true  Can notify: false
  Charac.: UUID: 49535343-aca3-481c-91ec-d85e28a60318
    Can read: false Can write: true  Can notify: true

Service Service: UUID: 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
  Charac.: UUID: 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Can read: false Can write: false  Can notify: true
  Charac.: UUID: 0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Can read: false Can write: true  Can notify: false
```

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic, in this case, are those for a UART communication:

```
Service Service: UUID: 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

use the notify of this one...
  Charac.: UUID: 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Can read: false Can write: false  Can notify: true
  Charac.: UUID: 0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

use the write of this one...
    Can read: false Can write: true  Can notify: false
```

There is not really a rule to it but u can use a tool on Android or IOS called `nRF Connect` and you can send and receive from characteristics to try them out. The OBD dongles are quite similar. In fact, many Chinese dongles use exactly the same characteristics (same firmware?). I can confirm that for Carista and VeePeak.

Comment: Hi, It seems my OBD2 dongle (AutoPhix 3210) has the exact same characteristics aswell. The question is, what command did you end up sending first to the WRITE characteristic and did you get an answer from the NOTIFY characteristic after that? I have sent a byte-array containing the mode (0x01) and the PID (0x0C) to it, but dont seem to be getting a response..

Comment: 'atd'
'atkw0'
'atsp0'
'ate0'
'ati'.
'ath1'
'ats0'
'atl0'
'atat1'

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I have a follow-up question: So if i send ‘ATD\r’ as a byte-array, I will get s notification you say? Is the ‘\r’ really needed? And how long do I wait before sending another command?

Comment: You send the next request when you received a response from the previous. I think the Bluetooth driver accepts Strings. It depends probably what you are coding on.

Comment: I am trying to do this via the C# BLE library of  alan Ritchie. I can only send byte-arrays, but that should be possible right? Is the “\r” needed too btw?

Comment: Yes byte array should be fine. I am not sure anymore if you have to add a return but you could just try and see. Also, the elm manual should state that. https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM327DS.pdf

Comment: Is there a way to identify the right characteristic for read and write/notify inside my app, maybe with a specific property of the characteristic? Would I have to just iterate over all characteristics and try them one by one (trial and error), or is there a more structured/efficient way of doing that?